# Angular 7, dynamically assigning values to formarray controls

Tags: angular, form-control, formarray, formgroups

In angular 7 , I am trying to make editable form with some initial values. I created a formgroup which also has formarray. I am trying to dynamically assign values to formcontrols , within formarray but formcontrol values are not being displayed on form.

Here is my html,

```
<form [formGroup]="UserForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
  <ng-container>
    <span>Group Name</span>
    <mat-form-field id="uName">
      <input matInput autocomplete="off" formControlName="GroupName">
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
  <br>
  <span>User Details</span>
  <br> 
  <div id="divUser"> 
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="UserData" class="mat-elevation-z8" formArrayName="UserRow">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index" [formGroupName]="index">
                  {{index + 1}}.
              </td>         
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Server Name</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index" [formGroupName]="index">
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput formControlName="username" autocomplete="off">  // this is showing blank fields
                  </mat-form-field>  
              </td>         
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="UserColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: UserColumns;"></tr>
      </table>   
  </div> 
  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And component code,

```
export class AdmissionComponent implements OnInit {
  public UserForm: FormGroup;
  public UserData;
  public UserColumns = ['id','username']  

  constructor(private formservice: AdmissionService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getservicedata('FIRST')
    this.UserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      GroupName: new FormControl(),     
      UserRow: this.formBuilder.array([this.CreateUser()])      
    });
  }

  onsetValue(result): void { 
    this.UserForm.controls['GroupName'].setValue(result.data[0].GroupName) // This is working and showing on html.      

    for (var key in result.data[0].usersRow) {
      if (key != '0'){ this.fnUserAdd(); }      
      // this.UserForm.value.UserRow[key].username = result.data[0].usersRow.username; // this is not working.
      this.UserForm.value.UserRow[key].username = 'testing'; // this is not wroking either
        };

        console.log(this.UserForm.value) // BUT this is perfactly showing data after setting up the values.
    }

    fnUserAdd(){
        (this.UserForm.get('UserRow') as FormArray).push(this.CreateUser());
        return this.getUserData();
    }
    getUserData(){
      this.UserData = this.UserForm.get('UserRow').value;
    }
    CreateUser(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
          username: '',
          userrole: '',      
          present:''
        })
    }
    getservicedata(UserId){    
        return this.admiserv.getDetails(UserId)
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            this.onsetValue(result)         
          });
    }
  submit(){
    console.log(this.UserForm.value)
  }
}
```

It shows blank input fields on html and when i put some values and click submit, it works and sends the values to function but not showing initial values in input fields.

Please suggest how to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please create a sample on stackblitz for this.

Comment: You have a duplicate identifier named `formservice` in your implementation. Plus you're also injecting two services as dependencies. Please share a minimal implementation of those two services as well.

Comment: Thanks @SiddAjmera. I changed the function name and updated question as well but still no difference.

Comment: I didn't say it will fix the issue at hand. I just said that we need more information in order to fix the issue at hand. Would you mind creating a sample stackblitz to work with and share it across so that we could have a look into it?

Comment: @SiddAjmera , i have been trying to create it on stackblitz  since morning but not able to fr various errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use setValue -or pathValue- to give value to a FormControl, FormArray or FormGroup-. So, I supouse you want write something like

```
const array=this.UserForm.get('UserRow') as FormArray;
for (var row of result.data[0].usersRow) {
   array.push(this.CreateUser());
   array.at(array.length-1).setValue(row)
  //or array.at(array.length-1).setPathValue({username:'test'})
}
```

Really, I suggest you change your function CreateUser by some like

```
CreateUser(data:any): FormGroup {
   data={username:'',userrole:'',present:'',...data}
   return this.formBuilder.group({
          username: data.username,
          userrole: data.userrole,      
          present:data.present
   })
}
```

So you can simple

```
const array=this.UserForm.get('UserRow') as FormArray;
for (var row of result.data[0].usersRow) {
   array.push(this.CreateUser(row));
  //or array.push(this.createUser({username:'test'})
}
```

and if you want create an empty formGroup, call as

```
this.CreateUser(null)
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khmcqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo but It is not working. throwing error "Cannot read property 'username' of null" in suggested function CreateUser(data:any).  And how the ngInit line "UserRow: this.formBuilder.array([this.CreateUser()])  " will change ?

Comment: ::glups:: a sintax mistake (are username:data.username,... -before username:data:''... I forgot remove the `:''` from a before coded-. Just corrected in answer. added a stackblitz. My apologies :(

Comment: Yes @Eliseo, i corrected this and it worked. Thanks a lot. I also learnt spread syntax from your answer.  :-)